# Show date on xAxes without labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to make an inline chart based on 2 values according to a date.
For the example I took only 3 values.

But I can not display values on the axes without using labels.
I do not want to define them because I wish to be able to choose if I display by day, month ...
And potentially I can have several values per day.
Sample of graphic that I want to realize : [image: sample]

```
    <div style="width:400px">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    var timeCheck = ['2017-09-21 11:30:51.418Z', '2017-09-25 10:52:30.966Z', '2017-09-25 12:35:51.118Z']
    var valueOne = [3578, 3110, 971]
    var valueTwo = [2516, 2516, 2516]
    var test = [{x: '2017-09-21 11:30:51.418Z', y: 3578},{x: '2017-09-25 10:52:30.966Z', y: 3110},{x: '2017-09-25 12:35:51.118Z', y: 971}]

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {

            datasets: [{
                label: '# the value One',
                data: valueOne,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 133, 27, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    '#ff851b'
                ],
                borderWidth: 2
            }, {
                label: '# the value Two',
                data: valueTwo,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(0, 116, 217, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    '#0074d9'
                ],
                borderWidth: 2
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the `data` property you can define a `labels` property, which is an array of labels, which can be a string with various content.

For example:

```
const labels = items.map(item => {
    // return the desired label for each item here
})

// ...

new Chart(context, {
  data: {
    labels: labels
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I wish to do without labels for more flexibility.